# Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0 Authentication required " in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I study Auth via Email verify in Laravel project. I'm having problem.

I used this gentleman's code. This is working perfectly.

https://github.com/SzaszSzilard/Laravel6Test

I could get "Please click the button below to verify your email address." mail from
 hello@example.com and mailgun.org setting. It took plently time to recive it to my registered email address(Gmail). I guess because it's example.com and unknown domain.

I have rental a server. so I changed hello@example.com and mailgun.org to my rental server domain and Email address at [.env] and [config/mail.php]. After I changed them I couldn't get verify email and I got Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0 Authentication required " error.
I searched at web and changed many parameter  [.env] and [config/mail.php]. but everytime I changed I got diffrenct error and I couldn't get verify Email address.

Could someone teach me how to solve this please?

**.ENV**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=myhost.sakura.ne.jp
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=support@myhost.sakura.ne.jp
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Laravel Framework is 6.18.13 and  I'm usiing Let's Encrypt SSL.

**UPDATE: I already did this**

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

his error normally occurs when the laravel smtp driver cannot authenticate with the smtp server, and this can be caused by many things, many smtp servers block smtp ports, for example google, but from my experience it is normal for the settings to be wrong.

check that you are using the correct MAIL_ENCRYPTION and check with your smtp service provider that smtp ports have not been blocked for you

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I've tried MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl .but I still have error. I'm not sure about port. you mean I should change  MAIL_PORT=25 ?

Comment: I changed MAIL_PORT as 25 It worked! Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad

Answer (score 0):

Possible your config is not cached.
You can run following command to get your app running.

`php artisan config:cache`

Comment: Thank you for answering me. sorry I didn't write that. I already did that. but same error.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I apreciate